# Soundcloud and waveform background changes while playing from options

Tags: javascript, soundcloud, waveform

After following the instructions for using [Waveform.js](http://waveformjs.org) and SoundCloud to generate a waveform, it looks great.  The issue is that when the stream starts the colors change, specifically the background of the waveform goes transparent. I can’t figure out how to prevent this or how to control the playback colors.

Here is an example, I changed the background of the container to red so you can see it. I am trying to avoid having to manipulate the container to achieve this.

[image]

And here is what happens when it starts to play. I’d like the play state to not change colors and to have control over this (to change the color of the buffer and played). Any ideas besides using the custom player which doesn’t allow manipulation of the wave form?

[image]

Code for setting up the [waveform](http://waveformjs.org/)

```
SC.get("/tracks/132744204", function (track)
{
    var waveform = new Waveform({
        container: topPlayer.get(0),
        height: "50",
        innerColor: "#eee",
        outerColor: '#000'
    });

    waveform.dataFromSoundCloudTrack(track);
    var streamOptions = waveform.optionsForSyncedStream();
    SC.stream(track.uri, streamOptions, function (stream)
    {
        topPlayer.stream = stream
        topPlayer.stream.play();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching through the source code for waveform.js, the way to manage the playing options is the following:

```
 var streamOptions = waveform.optionsForSyncedStream({
   playedColor: '#f00',
   loadedColor: '#f00',
   defaultColor: '#00f'
 });
```

This isn't documented anywhere so in the event someone else wants to control these colors, you set them on the streamOptions.